# Problems running Realm: Could not find io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:0.88.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: android, realm

I am trying to run the example projects from the Realm [git repository](https://github.com/realm/realm-java) using Android Studio.

I find that when I open any of the example projects I get the following error:

```
Error:Could not find io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:0.88.0-SNAPSHOT.
Searched in the following locations:
file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/0.88.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/0.88.0-SNAPSHOT/realm-gradle-plugin-0.88.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/0.88.0-SNAPSHOT/realm-gradle-plugin-0.88.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
file:/Users/username/.m2/repository/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/0.88.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
file:/Users/username/.m2/repository/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/0.88.0-SNAPSHOT/realm-gradle-plugin-0.88.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
file:/Users/username/.m2/repository/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/0.88.0-SNAPSHOT/realm-gradle-plugin-0.88.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/0.88.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/0.88.0-SNAPSHOT/realm-gradle-plugin-0.88.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/0.88.0-SNAPSHOT/realm-gradle-plugin-0.88.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Required by:
io.realm:adapterExample:0.88.0-SNAPSHOT
```

After some searching I found that someone else has encountered this issue previously and raised it as a git [issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1969) but can't understand how to implement the answer:

> There is a chance our 0.88.0-SNAPSHOT hasn't been deployed yet. You
>   can install it yourself locally by running ./gradlew installRealmJava
>   from the root folder

The original user who asked the question doesn't confirm if this fixes his/her problem.

I have done further research on this solution which has lead me further and further from finding a solution as each problem requires further deviation from the original issue.

Considering this ticket is over a year old I am surprised that more people haven't come across the issue I have.

Any help or advice would be very appreciated.

Comment: try run `./gradlew installRealmJava` in the realm root dir first.

Comment: I don't really understand what this is telling me to do. Which is the root directory? Once I find it do I need to run that code on its directory in the terminal?

Comment: After you cloned the `realm-java` project, just open a terminal window to get into the `realm-java` directory you just cloned, and type `./gradlew installRealmJava` from that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Realm 0.88 [has not been released to jCenter at the time of this writing](http://jcenter.bintray.com/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/) (~9AM EST Feb 23 2016).

You can switch back to the latest build (0.87.4) by [changing the contents](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/commit/d87064508514e5d23665909b024e50c61e67f6b1) of `version.txt` in the root directory. This, of course, will likely be missing some features so instead, [as per the README](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/README.md) you may want to add the [OJO](http://oss.jfrog.org/oss-snapshot-local/io/realm/realm-android/) repository (and then you can use the 0.88-SNAPSHOT build):

> If you want to test recent bugfixes or features that have not been packaged in an official release yet, you can use a -SNAPSHOT release of the current development version of Realm via Gradle, available on OJO

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:<version>-SNAPSHOT"
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local'
    }
}
```

Specifically, you must add:

```
maven {
    url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local'
}
```

to both the `repositories` nodes in the `examples\build.gradle` file (note I did this and successfully got the Realm-0.88-SNAPSHOT but then had a conflict with a support annotations library, so YMMV).