# Realm.io on android has issues with log4j2

Tags: realm, log4j2

I need to use log4j (v2) for my android app, but it seems to clash really badly with realm.io.  I created a dummy project to reproduce the issue and when I include log4j-core, I get the exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory.  But if I comment out the log4j-core import, it runs.  Note that my code does not yet use log4j, it simply includes it in its gradle file.

Here is my gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'de.mindpipe.android:android-logging-log4j:1.0.3'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.5'

    //commenting the following line will make the app run
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.5'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
}
```

Here is my activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //The below line crashes!
    RealmConfiguration.Builder r  = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(getBaseContext());
  }
...
}
```

Here is the exception I get.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory
   at io.realm.RealmConfiguration$Builder.<init>(RealmConfiguration.java:279)
   at com.myapp.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any input appreciated!

**Update**
My first thought too was to take out the 'exclude' statement as suggested by Remko but that made the build fail.  Taking this 'exclude' out gives this build error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor
    File1: C:\Users\fgagn_000\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.realm\realm-android\0.87.5\ab4e1fead1380252dad0e95658e53ea0c113e89c\realm-android-0.87.5.jar
    File2: C:\Users\fgagn_000\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-core\2.5\7ed845de1dfe070d43511fab321784e6c4118398\log4j-core-2.5.jar
```

**Update**
The error described above happen when I deploy to my Jelly Bean (API 16) emulator.  In fact, this error occurs up to API 19.  At API 21 (there don't seem to be an API 20 emulator) it works.

Comment: It seems to be the similar problem with https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#jackson-databind , can you please try to create a dummy `Observable` described there?

Comment: Tried both, adding the rxjava library or just the Observable class.  Still the same error.  I am now noticing a lot of "Cold not find method/class..." in the log. I wonder if I am using the wrong version of some dependencies.

Comment: I tried add log4j2 to my project. Didn't see crash. How did you use log4j2 in the project? Or can you share the test project with us? If you want to share it privately, you can send it to help@realm.io. Otherwise share it on any place i can get it.

Comment: I tried you project and I can confirm that https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2361 fixed the issue. The fix has been merged to master already, so you can play with the snapshot. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35566024/problems-running-realm-could-not-find-io-realmrealm-gradle-plugin0-88-0-snaps this one will help for using 0.88 snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

Log4j uses the annotation processor to deal with custom plugins.

Can you try not excluding that? So remove from your packaging options: 
exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'